# No login screen

Tags: 12.04

I installed GIMP editor and then rebooted the laptop. After it, I was unable to login and got stuck on the login screen itself. I have tried various commands in the full screen terminal but nothing helped. Now, after various efforts  I even the login screen has also gone. The only thing I see whenever I switch on the system is the ubuntu logo alongwith the orange dots. That's it. No progress after it whatsoever.  Please help.

Comment: It looks like your computer detects your monitor as secondary. Have you worked recently on double screen?

Comment: No, I haven't done anything like that. I have searched various commands regarding lightdm and gdm but that too didn't help me. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop detects your monitor as secondary. Open `~/.config/monitors.xml` in your favourite text editor (for example `nano`), search for your laptop monitor and replace `no` with `yes` in line:

`<primary>no</primary>`

Tell me if it works.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43827/discussion-on-answer-by-szczepan-no-login-screen).